# How can I determine whether a doc was synced from PouchDB to CouchDB?

Tags: react-native, couchdb, pouchdb

My app is using Pouch db to sync data from and to a remote Couch db.
The users are working with it mostly on a bad network strength and are not always able to sync all their data at once.
That's why I would like to display a list of documents which were not synced yet to the remote Couch db, but I'm struggling with it.

How can I determine if a certain doc was synced out to the remote?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use the "change" event during replication in PouchDb. This event gives a list of the documents involved so you can work out what has been replicated and what has not. See the PouchDb docs for more information:

[PouchDb replication in the API Guide](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication)